# How to catch an "Unexpected token END OF FILE" from an external library

Tags: java, json, exception

I am using `JSON simple` and  while it is reading text files which contain JSON objects, it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:257)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
at readjson.ReadJson.readFileToWriteJSON(ReadJson.java:121)
at readjson.ReadJson.main(ReadJson.java:40)
```

I have no clue how to catch this exception. Any idea?

**EDIT**

Here is the code:

```
 private static void readFileToWriteJSON(final File folder) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException  {

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {

        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        readFileToWriteJSON(fileEntry);
        } else {
            try{
            String query=fileEntry.getName();


            fop=new FileOutputStream(file+"\\"+query+".txt");

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

           File file = new File(fileEntry.getPath());

           Object object = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(file));//exception happens here.

           JSONObject obj= (JSONObject) object;

            parseJson(obj);

            for(String url:writeThis){
            fop.write(url.getBytes());
            fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
            }
            writeThis=new ArrayList<>();
        }
        }
        catch(){}//how to fill this part
    }
```

}

Comment: *how to catch this exception* - same way as any exception `try...catch`

Comment: BTW, maybe the file is empty?

Comment: @ScaryWombat but what would be the catch part?

Comment: @ScaryWombat and i am sure it is not empty cause i have already checked it.

Comment: well as I can not see any code of yours, I have no idea how it affects your on-going business logic.  At the very minimum, you would need to log the message.  If it is a user inputted filename that is being read, then you may wish to prompt the user again.

Comment: @ScaryWombat please look at my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove your try and catch as they are in the wrong place - assuming that you want to continue reading other files.

Then change your code to

```
Object object = null;
try {
    object = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(file));//exception happens here.
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); 
   continue;   // go to the top of the for loop
}
```

Comment: but why this exception happens? files are full and still throws exception.

Comment: If you are using http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/parser/package-summary.html then maybe it is a bug with this software.  Try using https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson or GSON - they are well know and well tested

Answer (score 0):

This is thrown from inside the library to your calling code. So find the calling line from your code to this error throwing code (at readjson.ReadJson.main(ReadJson.java:40)) and put a try catch there..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
try {
    // your code
} catch (EOFException e) {
   // handle EOF exception
} catch(IOException e) {
    // handle not expected exception 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```